# Create loop to find difference between current date and date of row below

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a dataframe which has a column of dates in increasing order like so (but many more)

```
QEP_subset <- data.frame("Date" = c("2020-05-10", "2020-05-24", "2020-06-07", "2020-06-28"))
QEP_subset$Date <- as.Date(QEP_subset$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
QEP_subset
        Date
1 2020-05-10
2 2020-05-24
3 2020-06-07
4 2020-06-28
```

I want to create a loop where I can find the difference (in days) between the next date in the row below and the current date, and then save this difference to a new column in the data frame (time_diff).

This is the goal:

```
        Date time_diff
1 2020-05-10        14
2 2020-05-24        14
3 2020-06-07        21
4 2020-06-28        NA
```

So far I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
theDate <- QEP_subset$Date[1]
end   <- QEP_subset$Date[length(QEP_subset$Date)]

while (theDate <= end)
{ 
QEP_subset[ ,time_diff := shift((QEP_subset$Date[theDate]), 1L, type="lag") - QEP_subset$Date[theDate]]
  theDate <- theDate + 1                  
}
```

But the 'shift' function isn't working for me and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions for a way to a) loop through the levels of a column of dates and b) extract the previous rows date would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe `library(data.table); setDT(QEP_subset)[, time_diff := as.integer(shift(Date, -1L) - Date)]`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way could be:

```
QEP_subset$Diff <- c(as.numeric(diff(QEP_subset$Date)),NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
QEP_subset$diff <-  shift(QEP_subset$Date, n=1, fill=NA, type="lead")  - QEP_subset$Date
```